# Start screen won't appear on restart button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, html-table

I am trying to get the restart button to make the start screen appear again. In the clearColors function I called a restart function which should show the start screen again. So far this hasn't worked. I had already have called the start screens main div, by (by classname .blankscreen) and set the style to none in the fadeOutEffect function for when the screen initially loads. Perhaps this is the problem. As you can see the restart function is working as I set the background color to red.

JS

```
function game() {

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
document.querySelector("#rst").addEventListener('click', clearColors);

    let colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "purple", "green", "orange"];
    let tabledata = document.querySelectorAll('td');

    let i =0;
    tabledata.forEach(td => {
    console.log(td);
    td.addEventListener('click', () => {
        i++;
        if (i > 0) {  
           tabledata.forEach(td => {   
           let newcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * tabledata.length)];
           td.style.backgroundColor =`${newcolor}`;
           td.innerHTML=`${newcolor}`;
           
           })
        }   
    });
  });


  function fadeOutEffect() { //fade out on click
    var fadeTarget = document.querySelector(".blankscreen");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
            setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('.blankscreen').style.display="none";
            }, 500)
            document.querySelector('.reset').style.display="flex";
        }
    }, 100);
    
} 


function clearColors() {
    tabledata.forEach(td => {
        td.innerHTML="";
        td.style.backgroundColor="transparent";      
    })
    restart();
};

function restart() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
        document.querySelector('.blankscreen').style.display="flex";
    }, 500);
}

}

game(); // call game function
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="blankscreen startgame" id="start">
          <p>Start</p>
          <button type="button" id="btn">Start</button>
      </div>
      <div class="reset">
          <!-- <p>Reset</p> -->
          <button type="button" id="rst">Reset</button>
      </div>
      <table>
          <tr>
            <th id="">squares</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Red</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
              <td>Yellow</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Purple</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>  
      </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.blankscreen {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 232.5px;
    width: 314px;
    top: 232.5px;
    background-color: rgb(237, 103, 103);
    z-index: 99;
}


table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 232.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* z-index: 99; */
}
td {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.reset {
    display: none; /* set to flex */
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 314px;
    margin-top: 475px;

}
.reset #rst {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just reverting what the Start button does, and also reverting the `td`s to the original position based on the `colors` array.

```
function game() {
  document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", fadeOutEffect);
  document.querySelector("#rst").addEventListener("click", clearColors);

  let colors = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "purple", "green", "orange"];
  let tabledata = document.querySelectorAll("td");

  let i = 0;
  tabledata.forEach((td) => {
    console.log(td);
    td.addEventListener("click", () => {
      i++;
      if (i > 0) {
        tabledata.forEach((td) => {
          let newcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * tabledata.length)];
          td.style.backgroundColor = `${newcolor}`;
          td.innerHTML = `${newcolor}`;
        });
      }
    });
  });
  var fadeTarget = document.querySelector(".blankscreen");
  function fadeOutEffect() {
    //fade out on click

    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        setTimeout(() => {
          fadeTarget.style.display = "none";
        }, 500);
        document.querySelector(".reset").style.display = "flex";
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  function clearColors() {
    fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
    fadeTarget.style.display = "";
    document.querySelector(".reset").style.display = "";
    tabledata.forEach((td, index) => {
      td.innerHTML = colors[index];
      td.style.backgroundColor = "";
    });
    //restart();
  }

  function restart() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      document.querySelector(".blankscreen").style.display = "flex";
    }, 500);
  }
}

game(); // call game function
```